# Can I ask about whether or not it's a good idea to talk about a specific previous experience when applying?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've checked the Tour and the Help center, and I'm having a doubt whether or not my question has its place on Workplace SE.

Basically, there was a software company for which I worked as an intern, during which I made a mobile application.

Although it sounds like a good idea to mention it when applying (for a mobile development job for example), there are some... details that make me wonder whether or not I'd better not mention it.

According to the [Help Center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), this question would have its place there, because we can ask question about:

> Finding employment (resumes/cv/cover letters, recruiters, hiring-managers, interviews, negotiations, etc.)

However, the [Tour](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tour) says that the question must be a:

> - Specific issues encountered navigating a professional environment
> - Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered pertaining to a workplace

But so far, I didn't have any specific issue with this... yet.

So, I was wondering if it was relevant to ask about it on the main site?

Comment: You can always ask. Worst case, it gets put on hold, in which case you may be able to edit it into shape. In the best case, you get useful answers. FWIW, this seems completely on-topic to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, by all means ask it - this is on-topic here.